# Flatlist Looping through nested array in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to loop through a nested array in my React native app.

I tried using a for loop, but that didn't work. I am still new to React so I'm not that familiar with how to loop

Now what I'm trying to do is to only display the data from `newRow` in each object from the `row` array

using `{ item.newRow[0].name }` does work I want to loop trough `newRow` to display all the newRows

How can I loop through all the rows and get all `newRows` to be displayed?

Example array:

```
  {
    id: 0, 
    text: 'View',
    newRow: [
    {id: 0, text: 'View'},
    {id: 1, text: 'Text'},
    {id: 2, text: 'Image'},
    {id: 3, text: 'ScrollView'},
    {id: 4, text: 'ListView'},
    ]
  },
  {id: 1, text: 'Text',
    newRow: [
    {id: 0, text: 'View'},
    {id: 1, text: 'Text'},
    {id: 2, text: 'Image'},
    {id: 3, text: 'ScrollView'}, 
    {id: 4, text: 'ListView'},
    ]
  },
  {id: 2, text: 'Image'},
  {id: 3, text: 'ScrollView'},
  {id: 4, text: 'ListView'},
```

Example Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList, Text, StyleSheet,View } from 'react-native';

const rows = [
  {
    id: 0, 
    text: 'View',
    newRow: [
    {id: 0, text: 'View'},
    {id: 1, text: 'Text'},
    {id: 2, text: 'Image'},
    {id: 3, text: 'ScrollView'},
    {id: 4, text: 'ListView'},
    ]
  },
  {id: 1, text: 'Text',
    newRow: [
    {id: 0, text: 'View'},
    {id: 1, text: 'Text'},
    {id: 2, text: 'Image'},
    {id: 3, text: 'ScrollView'}, 
    {id: 4, text: 'ListView'},
    ]
  },
  {id: 2, text: 'Image'},
  {id: 3, text: 'ScrollView'},
  {id: 4, text: 'ListView'},

]

// const rowsNewRow = rows[i].newRow

const extractKey = ({newRow}) => newRow

export default class App extends Component {

  renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <Text style={styles.row}>
        {item.text}
      </Text>
    )
  }

  renderLoop = ({item}) => {
   var items= [];

    for(let i = 0; i < item; i++){

      items.push(
        <View key = {i}>
          <View>
           <Text style={styles.row}>
            {item.text}
          </Text>
          </View>
          <View>

          </View>
          <View>

          </View>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }

  render(

  ) {
    return (
      <View  style={styles.container}>

      <FlatList
        style={styles.container}
        data={rows}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        keyExtractor={extractKey}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 20,
    flex: 1,
  },
  row: {
    padding: 15,
    marginBottom: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'skyblue',
  },
})
```

[Example App](https://snack.expo.io/@salman15/flatlist?session_id=snack-session-34Z4dLntx)

Comment: Take a look at Lodash flatten and flattenDeep functions for inspiration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking at including the items from your newRow array inside the row that you are creating in your FlatList.

This can be achieved by updating your `renderItem` function to something like this

```
renderItem = ({item}) => {
  let items = [];
  if( item.newRow) {
    items = item.newRow.map(row => {
      return <Text>{row.text}</Text>
    })
  } 

  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.row}>
        {item.text}
      </Text>
      {items}
    </View>
  )
}
```

What I am doing is

1. Create an empty array for holding the mapped `newRow` items
2. Check that the `newRow` array exists
3. If it exists then I am mapping it to an array
4. Update the return function so that it returns all the items

Here is a snack with the working code https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/flatlist-with-nested-array

Answer (score 2):

`FlatList` component will loop through your `row` dataset. You can pass entire row object in the `renderItem` and return a component with newRow as dataset.

```
<FlatList
   style={styles.container}
   data={rows}
   keyExtractor={extractKey}       
   renderItem={rowsProps=> {
     return <ListItem {...rowsProps} />;
   }}
 />
```

Where ListItem will have access to each element of `row`. `ListItem` can something be like

```
  const ListItem = (props) => {
       return 
          <View>
            {props.newRow.map(newProp => {
              return <View>newProp.text</View>;
            })}
          </View>

    }
```